# Why the DoubleAnimation using ProgressBar Value doesn't work?

Tags: wpf, xaml, progress-bar

I want to make a custom progress bar by changing his progress color. So I wrote a code to create it.

**My code:**

```
<Style x:Key="colorizedPB" TargetType="ProgressBar">
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red"/>
    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="LightGray"/>
    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1"/>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="ProgressBar">
                <Viewbox>
                    <Border HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="{TemplateBinding Width}" Height="{TemplateBinding Height}">
                        <Rectangle x:Name="rect" Fill="Red" Width="0" Height="{TemplateBinding Height}">
                            <Rectangle.RenderTransform>
                                <TranslateTransform X="0" Y="0"/>
                            </Rectangle.RenderTransform>
                        </Rectangle>
                    </Border>
                </Viewbox>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="ValueChanged">
                        <BeginStoryboard>
                            <Storyboard>
                                <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="rect" 
                                                     Storyboard.TargetProperty="Width"
                                                     To="{Binding Path=Value,RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"
                                                     Duration="0:0:0.1"/>
                            </Storyboard>
                        </BeginStoryboard>
                    </EventTrigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>

<Canvas Grid.Column="1" Margin="8,102,10,53">
                <ProgressBar x:Name="progressBar" Style="{DynamicResource colorizedPB}" Width="200" Height="20"/>
</Canvas>
```

I was expecting this code to work but it didn't. I think the `To` property of `DoubleAnimation` has a problem. How can I make it work?

Comment: In this case it would probably be easier if just have a visual example of what you're after and allow us to just show you a way to accomplish it. As it sits I see how you have your rect sitting in a Border which will currently inherit the Width property of 200. You don't however have a min/max set for progress value and I'm not sure you're actually catching your valuechanged event amongst other things. Do you have an example of what you hope to accomplish?

Comment: @ChrisW. , I found a solution after some challenging researches and tries. You can find it below and take a look. But I am still looking for a solution that only uses XAML.

Comment: So your goal is just to make a progress bar that looks like that?

Comment: Yes, it was. Now I want to set a textblock on the middle of it. And I have a problem again:) If you want to help you can take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39171011/how-to-bind-the-progressbar-value-to-textbox-in-resourcedictionary?noredirect=1#comment65685482_39171011

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution by myself using code behind and XAML both. But I will be appreciated if someone answers using only XAML.

**XAML Style Code:**

```
<Style x:Key="colorizedPB" TargetType="ProgressBar">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red"/>
        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="LightGray"/>
        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1"/>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="ProgressBar">
                    <Viewbox>
                        <Border HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="{TemplateBinding Width}" Height="{TemplateBinding Height}"
                                BorderBrush="Gray" BorderThickness="1">
                            <Rectangle x:Name="rect" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Fill="{TemplateBinding Background}" Width="0" Height="{TemplateBinding Height}">
                                <Rectangle.RenderTransform>
                                    <TranslateTransform X="0" Y="0"/>
                                </Rectangle.RenderTransform>
                            </Rectangle>
                        </Border>
                    </Viewbox>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

**Code behind:**

```
void progressBar_ValueChanged(object sender, RoutedPropertyChangedEventArgs<double> e)
    {
        var template = progressBar.Template;

        //Find the Rectangle in the ControlTemplate
        var layer = (Rectangle)(template.FindName("rect", progressBar));

        //Calculate the increment amount depending maxValue and Width
        double artis = progressBar.Value * progressBar.Width / progressBar.Maximum;

        DoubleAnimation anim = new DoubleAnimation(toValue: artis, duration: TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(100));

        layer.BeginAnimation(Rectangle.WidthProperty, anim);
    }
```

**Result:**

[image: The Result]